# Replace values from filtered data

Tags: arrays, vue.js, logic

I have this arrays.

```
filteredData = [ {roles: 1,2,3,4},
                 {roles: 4,3,2,1} ]

role = [ {role_id: 1, role_name: User},
         {role_id: 2, role_name: Coach},
         {role_id: 3, role_name: Admin},
         {role_id: 4, role_name: Participator} ]
```

How can I change the `roles` in `filteredData` into `role_name` based on `role_id`?

Comment: You can use `filter` function to get role_name base on role_id
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter?retiredLocale=vi

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at following snippet please :

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data() {
    return {
      email: null,
      filteredData: [{ind_id: 1, first_name: "aaa", last_name: "bbb", email: "aa@bb.com", roles: [1,2]}, {ind_id: 2, first_name: "ccc", last_name: "ddd", email: "cc@bb.com", roles: [2, 3, 4]}],
      roles: [{role_id: 1, role_name: "Participant"}, {role_id: 2, role_name: "Coach"}, {role_id: 3, role_name: "Admin"}, {role_id: 4, role_name: "User"}]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    //  use map and find to extract role names
    getRoles(r) {
      return r.map(r => r.name = this.roles.find(f => f.role_id === r).role_name)
    },
    searchResult(e) {
      this.filteredData = this.fetchedData.filter((data) => {
        return (
          data.email.toLowerCase().includes(this.email.toLowerCase()) ||
          data.first_name.toLowerCase().includes(this.email.toLowerCase()) ||
          data.last_name.toLowerCase().includes(this.email.toLowerCase())
        );
      });
    }
  }
})

const filteredData = [ {roles: [1,2,3,4]},
                 {roles: [4,3,2,1]} ]

const role = [ {role_id: 1, role_name: 'User'},
         {role_id: 2, role_name: 'Coach'},
         {role_id: 3, role_name: 'Admin'},
         {role_id: 4, role_name: 'Participator'} ]
const getRoles = (r) => {
  return r.roles.map(r => r.name = role.find(f => f.role_id === r).role_name)
}

console.log(getRoles(filteredData[0]))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <input v-model="email" id="criteria" placeholder="Search a User" class="input1" required />
  <button @click="searchResult" label="Find">search</button>
    <table id="table">
      <tr>
        <th>First name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Roles</th>
        <th>Actions</th>
      </tr>
      <tr v-for="data in filteredData" :key="data.ind_id" :value="data.ind_id">
        <td>{{ data.first_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ data.last_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ data.email }}</td>
           <!--  call method and pass roles to get role names -->
        <td>{{ getRoles(data.roles) }}</td>
        <td>
          <button @click="sendProps(data)">
            Edit
            <i class="fa-regular fa-edit" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: My filteredData.roles is not in an array. The map is not working.

Comment: @Three_L_Some hey mate, this is not a valid js object `{roles: 1,2,3,4}` it must be array `roles:[1,2,3,4]`

Comment: I fixed it man! Thank you so much for the help and detailed changes. Hope you live a long life!

Answer (score 0):

Observation **:** `roles` inside `filteredData` not containing a valid value. It should be an array.

My implementation approach, I am converting the role array into a `key: value` pair object. So that I can easily bind the `role_name` easily while iterating filteredData array.

Demo **:**

```js
const filteredData = [
  { roles: [1,2,3,4] },
  { roles: [4,3,2,1] }
];

const role = [
  {role_id: 1, role_name: 'User'},
  {role_id: 2, role_name: 'Coach'},
  {role_id: 3, role_name: 'Admin'},
  {role_id: 4, role_name: 'Participator'}
];

const roleObj = {};

role.forEach(obj => {
    roleObj[obj.role_id] = obj.role_name
});

const res = filteredData.map(obj => {
    return obj.roles.map(roleId => {
    return roleObj[roleId]
  });
});

console.log(res);
```